# Getting an ID of each record in a HAVING (COUNT) query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

EDIT (as requested):
I've updated the sample data to show all the REAL data that I get when I run that SELECT on my database. I can confirm that the data IS BAD - it contains duplicate records. There was a bug in the application and the database did not have a unique constraint on (question,attempt,track_number). I'm trying to clean out the bad data - the duplicate records. To do that I need to get the tbl_survey.id (PK) values for those bad records.

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_survey(
    id [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    question [bigint] NOT NULL,
    attempt [bigint] NOT NULL,
    track_number [int] NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT tbl_survey_id_pk PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([id] ASC)
)
```

Data:

```
id      question  attempt track_number  track_number_count
315 8418    2   2
316 8418    1   2
317 8418    2   2
318 8418    2   2
319 8418    1   2
320 8418    1   2
321 8418    1   2
323 8418    1   2
324 8418    1   2
325 8418    1   2
326 8418    1   2
327 8418    2   2
328 8418    1   2
329 8418    1   2
330 8418    1   2
331 8418    1   2
332 8418    1   2
333 8418    1   2
334 8418    1   2
335 8418    1   2
336 8418    1   2
337 8418    1   2
338 8418    1   2
339 8418    1   2
340 8418    1   2
341 8418    1   2
342 8418    1   2
343 8418    1   2
344 8418    1   2
345 8418    1   2
346 8418    1   2
347 8418    1   2
348 8418    1   2
349 8418    1   2
350 8418    2   2
351 8418    1   2
352 8418    2   2
353 8418    1   2
355 8418    1   2
357 8418    1   2
358 8418    1   2
359 8418    1   2
360 8418    1   2
361 8418    1   2
362 8418    1   2
363 8418    1   2
364 8418    1   2
365 8418    1   2
366 8418    1   2
367 8418    1   2
368 8418    1   2
369 8418    1   2
370 8418    1   2
371 8418    1   2
372 8418    1   2
373 8418    1   2
375 8418    1   2
376 8418    1   2
377 8418    2   2
378 8418    1   2
379 8418    2   2
```

Using the above MSSQL 2008 R2 table and data this query limits the retrieved data to just the rows that I want (i.e. the data above):

```
SELECT
    question,
    attempt,
    track_number,
    COUNT (track_number) AS track_number_count
FROM tbl_survey
WHERE attempt = 8418
GROUP BY
    question,
    attempt,
    track_number
HAVING (COUNT(track_number_count) > 1 )
ORDER BY attempt, question;
```

How do I change that SELECT query so that it also gives me the 'id' column from that table for each of the rows returned?

Currently I'm getting:

```
question  attempt  track_number  track_number_count
315       8418     2             2
317       8418     1             2
```

I want the extra id column:

```
id      question  attempt  track_number  track_number_count
476585  315       8418     2             2
476606  317       8418     1             2
```

What have I done wrong? How do I get the id column to display?

Thanks.

Comment: THis is not a real question: ID is identity, each row have a different ID, if you group by ID all groups will have at least 1 member, then, adding your having question ( count > 1 ), never you will get results.

Comment: Thanks. I know that adding "group by ID" is wrong. But how do I get the ID values for those rows that this query does return:

 SELECT
  question,
  attempt,
  track_number,
  COUNT (track_number) AS track_number_count
 FROM tbl_survey
 WHERE attempt = 8418
 GROUP BY
  question,
  attempt,
  track_number
 HAVING (COUNT(track_number_count) > 1 )
 ORDER BY attempt, question;

Comment: The data provided does not match the results provided - **none** of them would have a count greater than 0 (even if you omitted the id from the group expression). Can you edit the question to make the sample data and output match?

Comment: Try 'MIN(id) AS id' to get the smallest matching id per row.

Comment: @luisdev, you are looking for `GROUP_CONCAT()`, an aggregate function that is not available in sql-server but they are lot of samples to do workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
SELECT
    MAX(id),
    question,
    attempt,
    track_number,
    COUNT(track_number) AS track_number_count
FROM
    tbl_survey
WHERE
    attempt = 8418
GROUP BY
    question,
    attempt,
    track_number
HAVING
    (COUNT(track_number_count) > 1 )
ORDER BY
    attempt,
    question;
```

Answer (score 2):

I think once you get the details you want then you can work it back to those IDs that meet the criteria:

```
SELECT id,      question,  attempt,  track_number,  track_number_count
from 
tbl_survey ts
inner join 
(
    SELECT
    question,
    attempt,
    track_number,
    COUNT (track_number) AS track_number_count
FROM tbl_survey
WHERE attempt = 8418
GROUP BY
    question,
    attempt,
    track_number
HAVING (COUNT(track_number_count) > 1 )
) as matching
on
(ts.question=matching.question and ts.attempt=matching.attempt and ts.track_number=matching.track_number)
ORDER BY ts.attempt, ts.question;
```

Something like that anyway but I'm not 100% sure it even makes sense.

Comment: Ambiguous column name 'question'...http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ab8ef/1

Comment: SELECT ts.id, ts.question, ... can't get the sqlfiddle to build schema.  Thanks for doing it though.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure, i couldn't get the query to run on sql fiddle, but it semes like you are lowering the granularity of your group by and therefore yielding a lower count.

That lower count, is not > 1.  Therefore you're missing rows.

Try changing the last line here to >**=** 1:

```
HAVING (COUNT(track_number_count) >= 1 )
```

Comment: Why the -1?  i was trying to explain the impact of group by's and shifting grain's when a having clause is present.

Comment: I do want to "miss rows". I specifically only want rows where "COUNT(track_number_count) > 1"

Comment: If you change the grain (by adding ID to the group by) there are no rows that fit that criteria.  Aggregates are only relevant in the context of which they are grouped  by.